# IOS Accessibility selected marker not moving

Tags: ios, accessibility, voiceover

We have invisible UIViews set up and marked as accessible for IOS voiceover. Swiping moves the outline marker from one view to another, yet if we move a view's position using SetFrame, and it is the currently selected view for Voiceover, it doesn't move the frame with it. If we then touch or drag onto the same view, it picks up the new position.

Any ideas how to move the outline programmatically ?

Here's our rough code

We maintain an array of areas and texts on screen that need to be accessibility views and create and update invisible views over these areas.

// If we detect a new view is needed

```
LocalAccBounds[i].view= [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 64, 64)] retain];
LocalAccBounds[i].view.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
LocalAccBounds[i].view.isAccessibilityElement = true;
LocalAccBounds[i].view.userInteractionEnabled = false;      
LocalAccBounds[i].view.accessibilityLabel = [NSString stringWithCString:LocalAccBounds[i].txt encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
UIViewController * lVC = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] rootViewController];
[lVC.view addSubview:LocalAccBounds[i].view];
```

// If we detect an existing view has moved

```
[LocalAccBounds[i].view setFrame:CGRectMake(LocalAccBounds[i].x1*xsc,LocalAccBounds[i].y1*ysc, LocalAccBounds[i].x2*xsc-LocalAccBounds[i].x1*xsc, LocalAccBounds[i].y2*ysc-LocalAccBounds[i].y1*ysc-0)];
```

// If we detect an existing view is no longer needed

```
[LocalAccBounds[i].view removeFromSuperview];
[LocalAccBounds[i].view release];
LocalAccBounds[i].view=0;
```

When we move an existing view, e.g. we scroll them left or right, it doesn't move the outline with the view. Sometimes a second or so later the outline marker moves to one or other of the existing outlines, not necessarily where the last touch was though.

Thanks

Shaun

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your use case but according to what's written in your post, I suggest to :

- Create your accessibility view with the [`accessibilityFrameInContainerSpace`](http://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios.html#grouping-elements) property.
- Take a look at the [`UIAccessibilityFocus`](http://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios.html#focus-an-element) informal protocol to follow you accessible element focuses.

These two leads should help you to get your purpose according to what I vaguely understood of your problem.